# Append stored procedure with query

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Testing]
@PageIndex INT = 1
  ,@PageSize INT = 10
  ,@type nvarchar(max)
  ,@city nvarchar(max)
  ,@query nvarchar(max)
  ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
  AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @mainQuery nvarchar(MAX),
        @paramDeclaration nvarchar(500);
SET @paramDeclaration = ' @PageIndex INT = 1
                         ,@PageSize INT = 10
                         ,@type nvarchar(max)
                         ,@city nvarchar(max)
                         ,@RecordCount INT';
SET @mainQuery = '

  ;WITH DistinctMails AS
(
select  Unit_Table.Unit_title, Vendor_Base_Price.Base_Price, Vendor_Base_Price.showprice, Category_Table.Title, Vendor_Registration.Business_Name, 
                     Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Street_Address, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Locality, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Nearest_Landmark, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.City, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.State, 
                     Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Country, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.PostalCode, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Latitude, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Longitude, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.ImageUrl, 
                     Vendor_PrimaryInfo.ContactNo, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Email,Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID,Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID,Vendor_Value_Table.Value_Text

 ,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID ORDER BY Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID) AS RowNum

  FROM  Unit_Table INNER JOIN
                     Vendor_Base_Price ON Unit_Table.Unit_ID = Vendor_Base_Price.Unit_ID INNER JOIN
                     Vendor_PrimaryInfo ON Vendor_Base_Price.Vendor_ID = Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID INNER JOIN
                     Vendor_Registration ON Vendor_Base_Price.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID AND 
                     Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID INNER JOIN
                     Category_Table ON Vendor_Registration.Category_ID = Category_Table.Category_ID
                     LEFT JOIN
                     Vendor_Value_Table ON Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Value_Table.Vendor_ID LEFT JOIN
                     Feature_Table ON Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID = Feature_Table.Feature_ID
                 where Vendor_Registration.Category_ID=@type and Vendor_PrimaryInfo.City=@city'
                 SET @mainQuery = @mainQuery + @query +'

)
SELECT * into #Results  
FROM DistinctMails
WHERE RowNum = 1
  SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM #Results

  SELECT * FROM #Results
  WHERE RowNum BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

  DROP TABLE #Results'
  exec sp_executesql @mainQuery, @paramDeclaration, @PageIndex = @PageIndex, @PageSize = @PageSize, @type = @type,
                                                  @city = @city, @RecordCount = @RecordCount
  END
```

**Can not Giving RecordCount as Output **
Kindly give some opinion i m stuck here
thanks in advance

As you can see I have a variable named `@query`, I just want to append query in it which contain various and and or operator how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should prepare query as string and then use [dynamic sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.110).aspx) to execute it.

```
sp_executesql [ @stmt = ] statement
[ 
  { , [ @params = ] N'@parameter_name data_type [ OUT | OUTPUT ][ ,...n ]' } 
     { , [ @param1 = ] 'value1' [ ,...n ] }
]
```

example, tested at my SQL Server 2012, can be different in older versions.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @conditions NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @combinedQuery NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @testValue NVARCHAR(100),
        @testValue2 Int,
        @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500);
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@parameter NVARCHAR(100), @testValue2 Int OUTPUT';
SET @testValue = 'HelloWorld'
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.Localizations'
SET @conditions = ' WHERE Value =@parameter SET @testValue2 = 33'
SET @combinedQuery = @query + @conditions

exec sp_executesql @combinedQuery,@ParmDefinition, @parameter = @testValue,   @testValue2 = @testValue2 OUTPUT
SELECT  @testValue2
```

You procedure will be converted to something like that:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetVendorsPageWise
       @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@type nvarchar(max)
      ,@city nvarchar(max)
      ,@query nvarchar(max)
      ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @mainQuery nvarchar(MAX),
            @paramDeclaration nvarchar(500);
    SET @paramDeclaration = ' @PageIndex INT = 1
                             ,@PageSize INT = 10
                             ,@type nvarchar(max)
                             ,@city nvarchar(max)
                             ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT';
    SET @mainQuery = 
    'SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID asc) AS RowNumber,
        Unit_Table.Unit_title, Vendor_Base_Price.Base_Price,        
        Vendor_Base_Price.showprice, Category_Table.Title,    
        Vendor_Registration.Business_Name, 
        Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Street_Address, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Locality, 
        Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Nearest_Landmark, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.City, 
        Vendor_PrimaryInfo.State, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Country, 
        Vendor_PrimaryInfo.PostalCode, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Latitude, 
        Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Longitude, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.ImageUrl, 
        Vendor_PrimaryInfo.ContactNo, Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Email, 
        Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID, Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID,
        Vendor_Value_Table.Value_Text
    INTO #Results
    FROM  
        Unit_Table 
    INNER JOIN
        Vendor_Base_Price ON Unit_Table.Unit_ID = Vendor_Base_Price.Unit_ID 
    INNER JOIN
        Vendor_PrimaryInfo ON Vendor_Base_Price.Vendor_ID = Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID 
    INNER JOIN
        Vendor_Registration ON Vendor_Base_Price.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID 
                            AND Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID 
    INNER JOIN
        Category_Table ON Vendor_Registration.Category_ID = Category_Table.Category_ID
    LEFT JOIN
        Vendor_Value_Table ON Vendor_Registration.Vendor_ID = Vendor_Value_Table.Vendor_ID 
    LEFT JOIN
        Feature_Table ON Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID = Feature_Table.Feature_ID
    WHERE
        Vendor_Registration.Category_ID = @type 
        AND Vendor_PrimaryInfo.City = @city '

    SET @mainQuery = @mainQuery + @query +
    'ORDER BY 
        Vendor_PrimaryInfo.Vendor_ID

    SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM #Results

    SELECT * 
    FROM #Results
    WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

    DROP TABLE #Results'

    exec sp_executesql @mainQuery, @paramDeclaration, @PageIndex = @PageIndex, @PageSize = @PageSize, @type = @type,
                                                      @city = @city, @RecordCount = @RecordCount OUTPUT
END
```

Comment: You should convert all code in stored procedure to string, append it with query conditions and execute it. Added example to my answer. Hope this will help.

Comment: As you can see in my procedure that where is not the last line its in middle so how could i use SET combinedQuery = query + conditions

Comment: if you append my procedure it would be very greatful thanks

Comment: i really appreciate your help but stuck some where i edited the revised code also kindly suggest

Comment: Updated example, added output parameter. You should not update you question when you ask something new, you should create new one.

Comment: ok i will keep this in mind but i didnt see any difference compare to previous code this updated example of yours is also giving RecordCount to null while Query is returning Values

Comment: I updated example code... `SET @ParmDefinition = N'@parameter NVARCHAR(100), @testValue2 Int OUTPUT';` You need to add **OUTPUT** keyword `exec sp_executesql @combinedQuery,@ParmDefinition, @parameter = @testValue,   @testValue2 = @testValue2  OUTPUT`. Now also added OUTPUT parameter to you stored procedure.

Comment: as you can see my stored procedure is returning first row  if multiple rows are coming I just want to do paging on that records and my query is failing to do so can you suggest a way I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you add some background? What is going wrong, what  works incorrectly. As you know i can not run you query, because i don't have you DB...

Comment: SELECT * into #Results  
FROM DistinctMails
WHERE RowNum = 1

Comment: I m using SELECT * into #Results  
FROM DistinctMails
WHERE RowNum = 1 to return distinct values and rownum return always 1 and when I pass this row num to perform pagination this will return all result set as  SELECT * 
    FROM #Results
    WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(PageIndex -1) * PageSize + 1 AND(((PageIndex -1) * PageSize + 1) + PageSize) - 1
Has ways rownum is equal to 1

Comment: I guess you should add GROUP By to select  Unit_Table.Unit_title, And remove SELECT * into #Results  
FROM DistinctMails
WHERE RowNum = 1
  SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM #Results. **GROUP BY** by all fildes will remove duplicates.

Comment: I cant because there are multiple ID associated with same Vendor

Comment: Can you then provide example, what do you mean by duplicate? Result set with duplicates and without.

Comment: thanks a lot now solved it really appreciate your help

Comment: Alexandr can u help me in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049777/records-with-multiple-conditions it would be very helpful