# How to use between clause on a nvarchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table which is attached in image here
[sample table values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HyKI.jpg)
I want that this conditions will return one row

```
   where Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID in (17,19) and value_text like 'Dhol Wala$Shahnai Wala' and value_text between 0 and 100`
```

because this represent to single vendor_id
but the problem is datatype of Value_Text Column is nvarchar(max)
how to do that kindly suggest.

Comment: Whats the DB ? Your only problem is using between with nvarchar ?

Comment: @AmirZiarati Nop this is the one problem as you can see that with same vendor id there are multiple values and i want run a query with feature_id and value_text like this SELECT * from
  Vendor_Value_Table where
  Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID in (17,19) and value_text like 'Dhol Wala$Shahnai Wala' and value_text between 0 and 100
and this is giving error it should have to be return one row because this condition is true

Comment: What does it mean ? Between 0 and 100 ? You cant have a text like 'dhol wala .....' And between 0 to 100 at the same time .

Comment: @AmirZiarati there are two rows one in which value is between 0 and 100 and one is in which value is Dhol Wala$Shahnai Wala and as you can see these both are true for one vendor

Comment: So why you used AND ? AND means having both this features at the same time . You must use or. Ill answer in a minute ;)

Comment: @AmirZiarati Thats because i strictly want the data in which these two conditions must follow

Comment: These two conditions at the same time ?

Comment: How do you want a text to be "dhol...." And also be convertable to number :/ at the same time ? :/

Comment: @AmirZiarati if int present then between else like

Comment: @AmirZiarati no text will not contain int

Comment: Ok . You mean if its numeric use between if its not numeric use like cluase ? Ok ? It doesnt need AND its one of them . Either this OR one.

Comment: @AmirZiarati yes exactly

Comment: @AmirZiarati actually its depend upon feature_id i know which feature id return int and which return text

Comment: Can numbers be negative ?

Comment: @AmirZiarati Feature_ID 19 is responsible for int and 17 is for text you can see enclosed image also for reference

Comment: @AmirZiarati NO Number will not be negative in any case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you wont have ANY NEGATIVE NUMBER You must cast nvarchar to Int for your between clause and set a default for the case its not cast-able like below:

```
 SELECT *
  From Vendor_Value_Table
WHERE (Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID in (17,19)) 
AND(
value_text like 'Dhol Wala$Shahnai Wala' 
OR 
 (SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(value_text) = 1 THEN CAST(value_text AS INT) ELSE -1 END) between 0 and 100
 )
```

We chose -1 as default becuase if its not cast able to number the between clause needs to be false always.

(IT WILL ONLY RESPONSE FOR THE NUMBERS LESS THAN INT RANGE)

Comment: value_text (SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(value_text)

Comment: can i use this without IN operator ex : SELECT *
  From Vendor_Value_Table
WHERE Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID =17 AND value_text like 'Dhol Wala$Shahnai Wala' AND Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID =19 AND value_text between 0 and 100 
As i know that Feature_ID 17 is giving text and Feature_ID 19 is giving int

Comment: Yes but (17 and like) OR (19 and between). DONT USE AND FOR ALL OF THEM. i think you need to make a better sense out of OR & AND

Comment: Actually there are two conditions which has to be merged first is this endor_Value_Table.Feature_ID =17 AND value_text like 'Dhol Wala$Shahnai Wala'

Comment: and second is Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID =19 AND value_text between 0 and 100

Comment: and these two conditions has to be merged with AND

Comment: You want both !!! Either with this condition OR with the other one. Just check what you say in DB and you will see that you are wrong. Then do what i say :)

Comment: When you say AND for all of your conditions you mean that you want the rows that have all these conditions at the same time. There wont be any row to have 17 and 19 feature id at the same time . So AND is wrong.

Comment: Can i create another thread where i can show you full problem with my stored procedure which i m using ?

Comment: Yes. But accept this and answer if it was helpful. Did you check what i wrote ? Did it worked ?

Comment: I accepted it but it didnt solved my problem :P i m creating another thread and post the link here is it seems ok?

Comment: :/ its 12pm here . Lets answer that tomoorrow.

Comment: I created the thread hope this will help you to understand the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051649/select-row-with-and-operator :)

Comment: how i can use two between in this query provided by you like between 0 and 100 or between 100 and 200

Comment: Why dont you use between 0-200 ?

Comment: because the value may be vary like between 0 and 100 or between 300 to 400 i dont want to use column name multiple time is there any way?

Comment: Tell exactly what you want ? Where you want between 100-200 and 200-300 ?

Comment: follow this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062927/how-to-supply-multiple-values-in-between-clause-after-where-clause